# Any Trick to Play HTML5 Video Player + MP4 Video in every browser?

Tags: html, video

I am building Self Hosted Video tutorial website.

I want to use HTML5 Player But with just one single Video format (mp4). But problem is that in some browsers like opera MP4 format is not supported.

I know for this i have to add multiple formats in html5 video player but having multiple versions (formats) of the same video will occupy multiple times of space in hosting.

Please give Suggestions.

Comment: Thought of adding a flash-based player as fallback?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use flash flow player. That works fine but problem is it plays video only after buffering complete video. It should start play instantly on clicking the play button.

Comment: That simply depends on two things: the encoding used for the video (mp4 is the container format, not the encoding), and the content-type you send the video with. If you use a streamable encoding and send it as video/mp4, it should work.

Comment: If you want to use HTML5 then having alternative encoding is how they have decided to solve this particular problem. If you don't want to have multiple versions then HTML5 is not for you - it's their chosen solution!

Answer (score 0):

*There is no support for html5 before IE 9.i think you should use **Video.Js**.The Video.js API allows you to control the video through javascript or trigger event listeners, whether the video is playing through HTML5, flash, or another playback technology.*

you can download it from here.
http://www.videojs.com/

read the documentation here.
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/v4.2.2/docs/index.md

Comment: If I am not mistaken video.js only adds a layer of customization on top of the html5 video tag and does nothing to solve mp4 compatibility issues. I am trying to find a cross browser solution to play mp4 (h264) and I will probably end up converting the mp4 to another format.

Comment: I finally used a simple player from mediaelementjs (http://mediaelementjs.com/) for IE and FF and an embedded divx player for chrome - download and install the player then generate the code here: (http://labs.divx.com/WebPlayerCodeGenerator)